# Searching for duplicates in multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional PHP array looking like this in JSON:

```
array = [{
          "id":"1",
          "key":"Ferrari",
          "type":"car"},
         {
          "id":"1",
          "key":"Red",
          "type":"color"},
         {
          "id":"73",
          "key":"Yellow",
          "type":"color"
         }]
```

Because it's actually a search result, I would like to, dynamically combine the results where the id's are the same. In other words the new array should look like:

```
    array = [{
          "id":"1",
          "key":"Red Ferrari",
          "type":"keyword"}, 
         {
          "id":"73",
          "key":"Yellow",
          "type":"color"
         }]
```

I have been looking at a lot of PHP functions, but they have a limited functionality, in multidimensional arrays. Any suggestions are appreciated :)
Many Regards
Andreas

Comment: Does a match always result in `type: keyword`? How are the names combined? Where do you know determine that it's *Red Ferrari* and not *Ferrari red*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no base functions to do as specific thing as you mention. So you can make something like this:

```
print_r(my_array_merge($data));
function my_array_merge($data)
{
    // sort all records by id to merge them later
    $data_by_id = array();
    foreach ($data as $item)
    {
        if (!isset($data_by_id[ $item['id'] ])) {
            $data_by_id[ $item['id'] ] = array();
        }
        $data_by_id[ $item['id'] ][] = $item;
    }
    // merge records with same id
    $return = array();
    foreach ($data_by_id as $id => $items)
    {
        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            if (!isset($return[ $id ])) {
                $return[ $id ] = $item;
            } else {
                $return[ $id ]['key'] .= ' ' . $item['key'];
                $return[ $id ]['type'] = 'keyword'; // I don't really get what you mean by 'keyword'
            }
        }
    }
    // reset keys before return
    return array_values($return);
}
```

Comment: well the 'keyword' was just to symbolize that it's no longer a definitive category like 'car' or 'color' but that does exactly what i need thx :)